# IJavaElement: execute a method

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

is it possible (and if yes: how) to execute a specific method in a IJavaElement (this method will only return a String)? If not, what are the possibilities to execute the method anyway?

Thanks
Matthias

PS: I am thinking in the way as the "inspect" works in eclipse

Comment: IJavaElement is an object used to model source. It has close to nothing to do with executing code.

Comment: I know, but i am looking for the best way to get from there to an executable piece of code. It could very well be that I always google for the wrong keywords but yesterday i was lost..